# how to show pandas data frame data as bar graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

how to show pandas data frame data as bar graph?

I have the data like below,

```
[{'index': 0, 'Year_Week': 670, 'Sales_CSVolume': 10},
 {'index': 1, 'Year_Week': 680, 'Sales_CSVolume': 8},
{'index': 2, 'Year_Week': 700, 'Sales_CSVolume': 4},
{'index': 3, 'Year_Week': 850, 'Sales_CSVolume': 13}]
```

I want to draw a bar graph where `Year_Week` should be in `X-Axis` and `Sales_CSVolume` should be in `Y-axis` like below screenshot.

[image]

I tried something like below,

```
Year_Week = []
Sales_CSVolume = []
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for idx, elem in enumerate(data):
    for key, value in elem.items():
        Year_Week.append(key == 'Year_Week')
        print(f"List element: {idx:>2} Key: {key:<20} Value: {value}")
        
plt.bar(Year_Week, Sales_CSVolume)
plt.show()
```

Above code is not work as per the screenshot graph. Can anyone help me to sort out this issue

Comment: Since you have a pandas dataframe, you can just do `df.plot.bar(x='Year_Week')`.

Comment: can you write the solution as answer @QuangHoang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = [{'index': 0, 'Year_Week': 670, 'Sales_CSVolume': 10},
 {'index': 1, 'Year_Week': 680, 'Sales_CSVolume': 8},
{'index': 2, 'Year_Week': 700, 'Sales_CSVolume': 4},
{'index': 3, 'Year_Week': 850, 'Sales_CSVolume': 13}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('index', inplace=True)

sns.barplot(data=df, x='Year_Week', y='Sales_CSVolume')
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91kF5.png)